# Slack notifications into coralogix

Tags: logging, integration, slack

I have slack channel that gets errors from multiple systems.
I want to send those errors to coralogix (log server).

Does anyone know if its even possible to send from slack to coralogix events?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with their Slack recorder -
https://coralogix.com/integrations/slack-data-ingestion/

BTW we also record pagerduty alerts - https://coralogix.com/integrations/pagerduty-data-ingestion/